# R syntax - Multivariate regression with an unknown coefficient or two, for a dummy (engineer)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Something I rather vaguely asked a few months back, saw the tumbleweed roll by (actually hacked some hardware in the time, to get a few answers) before the question was deleted, so I'll try again on a slightly more specific note, as there will be a cleaner / quicker way to get the answer.

If I know a regression equation derives a particular answer from a given set of variables and coefficients, but I don't know the values for at least one set, how can I model this in R / get R to have a guess at deriving the unknowns.

I ask as I was curious as to the maths embedded in number of Bioelectrical Impedance Analysis (BIA) devices I had around (A mix of Salter and Withings).
A quick Google revealed [dozens of published regression formula](http://pubs.sciepub.com/ijcn/2/1/1/), [to estimate: Total body Water / Fat / Lean Mass](http://ajcn.nutrition.org/content/64/3/436S.full.pdf), so was interested in which had made their way into the devices eg.

> Lukaski & Bolonchuk's (1988):
>
> **TBW** = (0.372 * HeightCM * HeightCM /
>   Resistance)  + (0.142 * massKg) - (0.069 * ageYears) + (3.05 * isMale)

...

> Matias et al. (2015):
>
> **TBW** = 0.286 + (0.195 * HeightCM * HeightCM /
>   Resistance) + (0.385 * massKg) + (5.086 * isMale)

Anyway the devices show the values of all but any Resistance (R) and possibly imaginary Rectance (X) values used (Withings), so thought I'd pester / learn a bit of R to see if there was an alternative to an afternoon without socks, but with a multimeter, a few bits of wire and a tweaked iPad.

**FYI:** My original five min play, in April, with a **Salter 9141 WH3R** suggested that:-

> **BodyFat %**  ~= x + (0.1 * AgeYears) + (0.4 * MassKg) - (8 * isMale) + y
>
> **TBW %**  ~= x - (0.2 * AgeYears) - (0.27 * MassKg) + (7.58 * isMale) + y

where x:  is some combination of:

**a * HeightCM^2 [+/] b * Resistance + c * HeightCM**

and with a **Withings WS-50** that:-

> **BodyFat %**  ~= X + (0.12 * AgeYears) + (0.29 * BodyMassKg) - (16.64 * isMale) + (5 * isJapanese) + z

where X:  is some combination of:

**a * HeightCM^2 [+/] b * Resistance + c * HeightCM + d * Reactance**

So is there a way that I a can ger **R** to have a guess at solving these unknowns, or must I stick with a: screwdriver, multimeter, tweaked iPad and / or logging proxy (mitProxy / HoneyProxy).

```
# Quick play to try to identify a few of the constants used by the Salter 9141 WH3R body fat scale
# sex ( 1 = male, 0 = female)
sex <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
ageYrs <- c(33, 33, 43, 43, 53, 53, 33, 43, 43, 53, 33, 43, 53, 33, 33, 43, 43, 53, 53, 33, 43, 43, 53, 33, 43, 53)
heightCM <- c(191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 181, 181, 181, 181, 171, 171, 171, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 191, 181, 181, 181, 181, 171, 171, 171)
heightCM2 <- heightCM * heightCM
massKg <- c(81.6, 83, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 81.6, 81.6, 81.6, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 81.6, 83, 81.6, 81.6, 81.6, 81.6)
bodyWaterPct <- c(62, 61.6, 59.9, 59.6, 57.9, 57.5, 58, 55.9, 55.5, 53.9, 53.2, 51.2, 49.2, 54.3, 54, 52.3, 52, 50.3, 50, 50.4, 48.4, 47.9, 46.4, 45.7, 43.6, 41.6)
bodyFatPct <- c(17.1, 17.7, 18.1, 18.7, 19.2, 19.8, 22.6, 23.7, 24.2, 24.7, 29.1, 30.1, 31.1, 25.2, 25.7, 26.2, 26.7, 27.2, 27.7, 30.5, 31.6, 32.3, 32.9, 37, 38.1, 39.1)

bodyFat.Salter = data.frame(sex, ageYrs, heightCM, heightCM2, massKg, bodyWaterPct, bodyFatPct)
bodyFat.Salter
summary(bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyFat1 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyFat2 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyFat3 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyWater1 <- lm ( bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyWater2 <- lm ( bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
fitBodyWater3 <- lm ( bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
summary(fitBodyFat1)
summary(fitBodyFat2)
summary(fitBodyFat3)
summary(fitBodyWater1)
summary(fitBodyWater2)
summary(fitBodyWater3)

library(glmulti)
fitBodyFatG1 <- glm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Salter)
test.model1 <- glmulti(fitBodyFatG1, level = 1, crit="aicc")
```

**Output:**

```
> summary(fitBodyFat1)

Call:
lm(formula = bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.42607 -0.20940  0.08889  0.15588  0.27051 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 101.747418   6.105948  16.664 1.39e-13 ***
sex          -8.007692   0.092545 -86.528  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs        0.105000   0.005899  17.801 3.80e-14 ***
heightCM     -0.591111   0.006422 -92.051  < 2e-16 ***
massKg        0.400794   0.079446   5.045 5.39e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2359 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9988,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9986 
F-statistic:  4442 on 4 and 21 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(fitBodyFat2)

Call:
lm(formula = bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM2 + massKg, 
    data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5345 -0.3141  0.1192  0.2024  0.3494 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.843e+01  8.409e+00   5.759 1.02e-05 ***
sex         -8.008e+00  1.238e-01 -64.696  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs       1.050e-01  7.889e-03  13.310 1.05e-11 ***
heightCM2   -1.626e-03  2.365e-05 -68.758  < 2e-16 ***
massKg       3.972e-01  1.063e-01   3.738  0.00121 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3156 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9979,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9975 
F-statistic:  2481 on 4 and 21 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(fitBodyFat3)

Call:
lm(formula = bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + 
    massKg, data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.12607 -0.02949 -0.01111  0.03162  0.17393 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 249.776918   9.660823   25.86  < 2e-16 ***
sex          -8.007692   0.026174 -305.94  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs        0.105000   0.001668   62.94  < 2e-16 ***
heightCM     -2.225111   0.104938  -21.20 3.53e-15 ***
heightCM2     0.004500   0.000289   15.57 1.20e-12 ***
massKg        0.400794   0.022469   17.84 9.48e-14 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.06673 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9999,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9999 
F-statistic: 4.448e+04 on 5 and 20 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

...

Call:
lm(formula = bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, 
    data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.19309 -0.12797 -0.06759  0.18355  0.31346 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.639382   4.922117   0.130  0.89788    
sex          7.576923   0.074602 101.565  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs      -0.202500   0.004755 -42.587  < 2e-16 ***
heightCM     0.432037   0.005177  83.460  < 2e-16 ***
massKg      -0.269841   0.064043  -4.213  0.00039 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1902 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.999, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9988 
F-statistic:  5087 on 4 and 21 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(fitBodyWater2)

Call:
lm(formula = bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM2 + massKg, 
    data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.25119 -0.16896 -0.09268  0.25881  0.39269 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.960e+01  6.631e+00   5.972  6.3e-06 ***
sex          7.577e+00  9.760e-02  77.635  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs      -2.025e-01  6.221e-03 -32.553  < 2e-16 ***
heightCM2    1.188e-03  1.865e-05  63.728  < 2e-16 ***
massKg      -2.670e-01  8.378e-02  -3.187  0.00443 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2488 on 21 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9982,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9979 
F-statistic:  2970 on 4 and 21 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(fitBodyWater3)

Call:
lm(formula = bodyWaterPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + 
    massKg, data = bodyFat.Salter)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.078205 -0.027991 -0.002778  0.038408  0.069017 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.200e+02  6.685e+00  -17.95 8.46e-14 ***
sex          7.577e+00  1.811e-02  418.32  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs      -2.025e-01  1.154e-03 -175.41  < 2e-16 ***
heightCM     1.763e+00  7.262e-02   24.28 2.58e-16 ***
heightCM2   -3.667e-03  2.000e-04  -18.34 5.63e-14 ***
massKg      -2.698e-01  1.555e-02  -17.35 1.59e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.04618 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9999,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9999 
F-statistic: 6.911e+04 on 5 and 20 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

...

Initialization...
TASK: Exhaustive screening of candidate set.
Fitting...

After 50 models:
Best model: bodyFatPct~1+sex+ageYrs+heightCM+heightCM2+massKg
Crit= -53.5831033999792
Mean crit= 117.663945821469
Completed.
```

**Withings**

```
...
fitBodyFat1 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, data=bodyFat.Withings)
fitBodyFat2 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Withings)
fitBodyFat3 <- lm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Withings)
summary(fitBodyFat1)
summary(fitBodyFat2)
summary(fitBodyFat3)

library(glmulti)
fitBodyFatG1 <- glm ( bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + heightCM2 + massKg, data=bodyFat.Withings)
test.model1 <- glmulti(fitBodyFatG1, level = 1, crit="aicc")
```

**Output:**

```
Call:
lm(formula = bodyFatPct ~ sex + ageYrs + heightCM + massKg, data = bodyFat.Withings)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3348 -0.5042  0.0597  0.5361  6.5767 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 120.39668    9.97149  12.074  < 2e-16 ***
sex         -16.64221    0.19636 -84.754  < 2e-16 ***
ageYrs        0.12039    0.01490   8.082 2.78e-13 ***
heightCM     -0.61641    0.01784 -34.552  < 2e-16 ***
massKg        0.29065    0.11652   2.494   0.0138 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9957 on 139 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9848,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9844 
F-statistic:  2251 on 4 and 139 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

...

Initialization...
TASK: Exhaustive screening of candidate set.
Fitting...

After 50 models:
Best model: bodyFatPct~1+sex+ageYrs+heightCM+massKg
Crit= 414.926000298605
Mean crit= 752.216409496029
Completed.
```

Comment: I would like to confirm that your question is this: I have data, and a candidate model, and I want to fit the model coefficients using the data.  I think you might be delighted to discover the power of the "glmulti" library, if you have the data.  The second model has no ageYears.  This makes me think you might have their model, but not their data, and you are trying to reconstruct a realistic form of the data.  Which is it?

Comment: The data's mine, simply obtained from tweaking (incrementing/decrementing)   the given: height, age, sex values for an actual mass and resistance reading, and noting the effect on the estimated values. I also have a few models for each device, to play with.

Comment: then glmulti is your "baby".  I'm going to assume the data above is representative.  This will turn into "how to determine the best model" from a soup of models given the style of data shown, and then some gross reality checks on the fit quality.

Comment: The Withings data frame also includes the +5% Japanese race coefficient, and the Athlete tweak, don't have value to hand (on phone)